# What does the term "suppose inductively" mean?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I am reading Analysis 1 written by Terence Tao. After a proposition (2.1.16) which is about "Recursive Definitions", he uses the term "suppose inductively" in proofs.

For example, Lemma 2.2.2: for any natural number n, n + 0 = n.

"We use induction. The base case 0 + 0 = 0 follows since we know that 0 + m = m for every natural number m, and 0 is a natural number. Now ***suppose inductively*** that n + 0 = n. We wish to show that (n++)+0 = n++. But by definition of addition, (n++)+0 is equal to (n+0)++, which is equal to n++ since n+0 = n. This closes the induction."

From the axiom about mathematical induction, I was under impression that one needs to prove a property works for n, and then also for n++, and then it is proven for all natural numbers.

So my question is, what does that specific term means and how or when we can use it in a proof.

Comment: “Suppose inductively” here means: “you are trying to prove the inductive step: $P(n)\implies P(n++)$. To prove the implication, you assume the antecedent, namely $P(n)$.” Or, in other words, it means “The induction hypothesis is that $n+0=0$”.

Comment: Thank you @ArturoMagidin. Just using the word "hypothesis" helps much more to grasp it, although the mentioned term in question is synonym. So if I just reiterate and to make sure I get it right: we prove the property for the base case (which for N is 0). Then we assume p(n) is true and if we can prove p(n++) is true. Then induction is closed.  Does it sound ok?

Comment: In general terms, yes; that’s how induction works.